# Grabbing inner html tags with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the objects for the inner `<li>` for this html. The one with the `id=config_#`

```
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_3"> Chrome 29</li>
      <li id="config_4"> Chrome 31</li>
      <li id="config_5"> Chrome 33</li>
      <li id="config_6"> Chrome 35</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_1">Firefox 11</li>
      <li id="config_2">Firefox 15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_0">Internet Explorer 8</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

My code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("browser_list");
console.log(list);

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    console.log(items);
}
```

`console.log(list)` works fine but when I try to `getElementsByTagName("li")` I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I feel as though I am missing something but as I am new to JS I am not sure what it is

Comment: Shouldn't it be `list[i].getElementsByTagName("li");`?

Comment: Why not access the objects directly with document.getElementById("");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is an array. Each element of the array is an `HTMLElement`

you'd need to use `list[i].getElementsByTagName`

JavaScript `Array`s don't have the method `.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: derp. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The getElementByClassName creates an array as more than 1 browser_list are found. So access it proper index.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("browser_list");
console.log(list);

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var items = list[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    console.log(items);
}
```

```html
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_3"> Chrome 29</li>
      <li id="config_4"> Chrome 31</li>
      <li id="config_5"> Chrome 33</li>
      <li id="config_6"> Chrome 35</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_1">Firefox 11</li>
      <li id="config_2">Firefox 15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="browser_list">
    <ul>
      <li id="config_0">Internet Explorer 8</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```